# Haskell Data.Binary: Shouldn't this be lazy? And how do I make it lazy?

Tags: haskell, binary, lazy-evaluation

I want to process a couple of hundred binary data chunks ("scenarios") for a Monte Carlo simulation. Each scenario consists of 1 million floats. Here's how I create a dummy binary file for the scenario data:

```
import Data.Binary 
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import Data.Array.Unboxed

scenSize = 1000000
scens = 100

main = do
    let xs = array (1,scenSize) [(i, 0.0) | i <- [1..scenSize]] :: UArray Int Float
    let l = take scens $ Prelude.repeat xs
    B.writeFile "bintest.data" (encode l)
    return ()
```

This works fine. Now I want to process the scenarios. Since there can be really a lot of scenarios (scens=1000 or so), the processing should be done lazily one chunk at a time. I tried `decodeFile`, but this does not seem to work:

```
import Data.Binary 
import qualified Data.Array.IArray as IA
import Data.Array.Unboxed as A

main = do
    bs <- decodeFile "bintest.data" :: IO [UArray Int Float]
    mapM_ doStuff bs
    return ()

doStuff b = 
    Prelude.putStrLn $ show $ b IA.! 100000
```

This program seems to first load all the data in memory, and then prints all the numbers at the end of the run. It also uses a lot of memory and crashes for scens=500 on my 32-bit Ubuntu machine.

What am I doing wrong? Is there an easy way to make the program run lazily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`decodeFile` is not lazy, just look at the source -it calls `decodeOrFail`, which itself must parse the whole file to determine success or failure.

EDIT:

So what I believe worked in the original `binary` is now broken (read: it's now a non-lazy memory hog).  One solution that I doubt is optimally pretty is to use lazy `readFile` and `runGetIncremental` then manually push chunks into the decoder:

```
import Data.Binary
import Data.Binary.Get
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.Array.IArray as IA
import Data.Array.Unboxed as A

main = do
    bs <- getListLazy `fmap` L.readFile "bintest2.data"
    mapM_ doStuff bs
    return ()

doStuff b = print $ b IA.! 100000
```

The important stuff is here:

```
getListLazy :: L.ByteString -> [UArray Int Float]
getListLazy lz = go decodeUArray (L.toChunks lz)
  where
    go :: Decoder (UArray Int Float) -> [B.ByteString] -> [UArray Int Float]
    go _ []       = []
    go dec (b:bs) =
      case pushChunk dec b of
        Done b' o a -> a : go decodeUArray (b' : bs)
        Partial f   -> case bs of
                          (x:xs) -> go (f $ Just x) xs
                          []     -> []
        Fail _ _ s -> error s -- alternatively use '[]'

    decodeUArray :: Decoder (UArray Int Float)
    decodeUArray = runGetIncremental get
```

Notice this solution didn't bother decoding then plumbing the list length through the decoder - I just changed up your generator code to output numerous arrays and not a list of arrays.

To avoid code like this I think pipes would be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be a rather harsh limitation, so I'm wondering if there's a easy way around it. For the time being, I'll try the following: Writing: Instead of encoding and writing a list of UArrays, I'll encode and write each UArray at a time. Reading: I'll read a chunk with defaultChunkSize, see if it decodes, otherwise read a bit more, and doStuff every time I have a complete chunk.

Comment: I was thinking on this and was surprised to find `fmap decode (readFile f)` doesn't do it (it doesn't decode lists lazily).  Now that I see this isn't trivially solved I'll give it another go in my free time.

Comment: @martingw Ok, I've posted an ugly but operational version that keeps the memory down.  Notice that at this point you'd probably be well served by learning and using pipes (`readFileP >-> runStateP [] decode >-> doStuffP` or some such)

Comment: Wow, thanks for putting so much effort into this!! This is amazing!